# Ocultar items de ListView en android y refrescar evento onClick

Tags: android, listview

Quiero ocultar los items según un parametro en un ListView. Tengo hecho esto y funciona:

```
    final ArrayList<? extends IMenuPrintable> adapterArray = sessionUser.getAvailableServicesForCategoryId(categoryId); 
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(this, adapterArray));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        
                menuItemClicked(position);        

        }
    });
```

La clase MenuAdapter es:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<? extends IMenuPrintable> items;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Integer> hiddenPositions = new ArrayList<>();

    public MenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<? extends IMenuPrintable> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

        if (this.items == null) {
            this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.items.size() - hiddenPositions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {    
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_menu_row, parent, false);
        }
        LDService service = (LDService) items.get(position);
        if (service.type.equals("4")) {
            hideItem(position);
            for (Integer hiddenIndex : hiddenPositions) {
                if (hiddenIndex <= position) {
                    position = position + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private void hideItem(int itemToHide) {    
        if (!hiddenPositions.contains(itemToHide)) {
            hiddenPositions.add(itemToHide);
        }    
    }

    private void menuItemClicked(int position) {

        ArrayList<? extends IMenuPrintable> services = sessionUser.getAvailableServicesForCategoryId(categoryId)
        LDService service = (LDService) services.get(position);
        //para cada 'service' compruebo ciertos parámetros...
    }
}
```

Con esto consigo ocultar los items pero la funcionalidad no existe. Cuando hago click en el primer item que se muestra tiene la posición del item ocultado. Es decir, se le pasa como parámetro a la función 'menuitemclicked()' la posición del item por defecto (el oculto). Yo quiero actualizar esa posición. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: La verdad es que así como lo planteas parece que todo está bien y sólo hace falta tu lógica de "actualizar", que por cierto no muestras qué haces ahí. ¿Podrías dar más contexto por favor?

Comment: Uso un ArrayList copia de adpterArray que le paso como argumento a MenuAdapter. Dependiendo de las posiciones realizo diferentes funcionalidades.  AdpterArray es: adapterArray = sessionUser.getAvailableServicesForCategoryId(categoryId); Y en la función 'menuitemclicked' hago lo mismo para obtener el ArrayList. @Chisko

Comment: Existe alguna forma de obtener la lista con la posiciones 'actualizadas' (cambiadas en la clase MenuAdapter) después de invocar a setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: sería mejor que en vez de explicarlo en comentarios editaras la pregunta con el código, aunque sea sólo las partes relevantes en lógica que no es de negocio, sobre todo qué haces en `menuItemClicked()` porque en teoría tu lista "actualizada" debería ser `items` y no creo que uses la otra _por error_

Comment: Ya entendí tu problema. Un segundo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `getView()` de un adapter no debe utilizarse para manejar la lógica de qué se va a desplegar, sino sólo para inflar la vista. El adapter sólo es un puente entre los datos y el UI y no debe ser más inteligente que eso. Saca la lógica de qué vas a mostrar de ese método

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_menu_row, parent, false);
    }         

    // Aquí debes hacer findViewById() como en una Actividad para cada elemento visual del item


    return convertView;
}
```

No estoy 100% seguro de dónde debe ir la lógica que pusiste ahí pero lo más seguro es que lo puedas hacer dentro de `menuItemClicked()`. Sólo recuerda que cada que escondes un item, lo tienes que quitar de `items` y llamar a `notifyDatasetChanged()`, por lo tanto también debes cambiar:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}
```

También te recomendaría usar el patrón de ViewHolder pues usas un ListView y puede llegar a laggearse tu UI.